# sql DB2 query to enumerate all paths from edgelist

Tags: sql, database, db2, recursive-query

I created a table in DB2:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  loan_id integer,
  client_id integer 
);
```

Inserted values into the table:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(
loan_id, client_id)
VALUES (1, '2');
```

Finally the table contains the following data:

```
loan_id     client_id
1           2
1           4
4           2
2           3
```

I want to run a SQL query which would enumerate (print) all the unique possible paths. An example output is given below:

```
1 -> 2
1 -> 4
4 -> 2
2 -> 3
1 -> 2 -> 3
4 -> 1 -> 2
4 -> 2 -> 3
4 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3
3 -> 2 -> 4 -> 1
```

I looked into the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963799/recursive-query-in-db2-to-get-all-items-in-the-chain?rq=1) and tried the following code, which gives error:

```
WITH links AS
( SELECT 
    loan_id, 
    client_id as c1, 
    client_id as c2, 0 as distance 
  FROM 
    mytable 
  -- recursion 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
     t.loan_id, 
     l.c1 as c1, 
     tt.client_id as c2, 
     distance+ as distance 
  FROM 
    links l INNER JOIN
    myTable t ON l.c2 = t.client_id
    AND l.loan_id != t.loan_id INNER JOIN
    myTable tt  ON t.loan_id = tt.loan_id 
     AND t.client_id != tt.client_id
 )
SELECT * FROM mytable t
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM links 
     WHERE c2 = t.client_id and c1 = 3);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Which error did it give?

Answer (score 0):

You can search in function SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH

[example here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-db2connectby/)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL SERVER VERSION:

`WITH allvalue as (
select loan_id id from mytable
union
select client_id id from mytable
),
allvaluewithnbcombi as (
select f1.*, (select count(*) from allvalue f2) nbcombi  from allvalue f1
)
,
tmprecurse (id, pathcalcul, rang, nbcombi) as (
select id , cast('' as varchar(50)) as pathcalcul,  1 rang, nbcombi from allvaluewithnbcombi
union all
select f1.id , cast(case when  pathcalcul='' then cast(f2.id as varchar(50)) else f2.pathcalcul + '->' + cast(f2.id as varchar(50)) end as varchar(50)) pathcalcul,

f2.rang + 1, f1.nbcombi
from allvaluewithnbcombi f1, tmprecurse f2
where f1.id<>f2.id and f2.rang<=f1.nbcombi
)
, resultat as (
select distinct pathcalcul from tmprecurse
where pathcalcul<>'' and pathcalcul like '%->%'
)
select * from resultat
order by len(pathcalcul)`

IN DB2 VERSION (not tested)

`WITH allvalue as (
select loan_id id from mytable
union
select client_id id from mytable
),
allvaluewithnbcombi as (
select f1.*, (select count(*) from allvalue f2) nbcombi  from allvalue f1
)
,
tmprecurse (id, pathcalcul, rang, nbcombi) as (
select id , cast('' as varchar(50)) as pathcalcul,  1 rang, nbcombi from allvaluewithnbcombi
union all
select f1.id , cast(case when  pathcalcul='' then cast(f2.id as varchar(50)) else f2.pathcalcul concat '->' concat cast(f2.id as varchar(50)) end as varchar(50)) pathcalcul,

f2.rang + 1, f1.nbcombi
from allvaluewithnbcombi f1, tmprecurse f2
where f1.id<>f2.id and f2.rang<=f1.nbcombi
)
, resultat as (
select distinct pathcalcul from tmprecurse
where pathcalcul<>'' and pathcalcul like '%->%'
)
select * from resultat
order by len(pathcalcul)`

I hope it's correct for you