# Given a transaction networks In DB2, Is there any way to select all pairs involved in a transaction?

Tags: sql, transactions, db2

I have a transaction network in DB2,which like below:

Table:trans

```
Originator  Beneficiary   Amount
A            B              100.00
C            D              150.00
B            F              400.00
D            Z              30.00
```

Let's say, we know A and C is the originator of transaction.
Now I `select * from trans where Originator in (A,C)`
Then I `select * from trans where Originator in (select * from trans where Originator in (A,C)`

Is there any method to tracing all counterpart in a single SQL? And is there better method to trace money?

Comment: Your queries don't make any sense - you're selecting everything from `trans` where the `Originator` is in the resultset containing... records in `trans` where the `Originator` is either `A` or `C`...  seems rather redundant, no?

Comment: Can you please show what your expected results are?  I can't follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sound like you need a rekursve solution like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963799/recursive-query-in-db2-to-get-all-items-in-the-chain

Comment: to Syyual,thank you for your quick response and I am sorry for my description on my question. Actually, I want to select all counterpart in a single SQL. My expected results like below: A-->B--->F--->.....;B--->C--->D--->Z; C-->/.... If given A for input, I want to get all transactions related to A and all the counterparts in my database.Now I just

Comment: select Beneficiary from the table using 'select Beneficiary from trans where Originator =A'; THEN I got B, and using select Beneficiary from trans where Originator =B' to get F,and so on. Any solution would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The expected result would be ,for A,                                                          Originator  Beneficiary   Amount
A            B              100.00

B            F              400.00